# Is the family of all finite union of difference of sets equal to the family of all finite union of difference of of the former family?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal G$ be any countable family of sets, where $\phi\in \mathcal G$.

Let $\mathcal G_1$ be the family of all finite union of difference of sets in $\mathcal G$.

Let $\mathcal G_2$ be the family of all finite union of difference of sets in $\mathcal G_1$.

May be I am misunderstanding the meaning of "finite union of difference" but to me here $\mathcal G_1=\mathcal G_2$. However my text book says it is not necessary. How so?

This is used in the textbook to prove the ring generated by countable generator is countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{G} = \{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2,3,4\}\}$.

Then $\mathcal{G}_1 = \{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,3,4\}, \{1,3,4\}, \{1,2,3,4\}\}$.

Now $\{3,4\} = \{2,3,4\} \setminus \{2\}$ is an element of $\mathcal{G}_2$, but $\{3,4\} \notin \mathcal{G}_1$.